# Passing associative array using jquery cookies, but getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, cookies

I have an array that I am pushing associative arrays into it.  I am then passing it through a cookie to another page, and then iterating the array to output on a page, but I keep getting Unexpected Token o error.  Below is the code.

```
VPC.vendorNameArray = [];
VPC.tempVendorName = [];
//in loop
nameArray.push({vendor: index, balance: value.balance});

$.cookie('nameArray', JSON.stringify(VPC.nameArray));
//On second page
$.extend(nameArray, JSON.parse($.cookie('nameArray')));
$.each(VPC.tempVendorName ,function(index, value){
var stuff = '<div onclick="javascript:vendorSelection(\'' + value.vendor + '\')">' + value.balance + '</div>';
     $('.vendorContent').append(stuff);                 
});
```

Comment: you might need to serialize first some of those values you try to stringify

Comment: On the second page, before the `$.extend()` call, what does `console.log( $.cookie('nameArray') );` show?

Comment: @Thomas Why? How? What would that fix?